# Looking for a late 80's (or possibly early 90's) D&D one-shot adventure based around a bar room brawl

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, published-adventures, product-identification, one-shot

About 20-25 or so years ago, our group played a D&D one-shot adventure that was entirely based around a bar room brawl. It started out with us in the inn post-adventure, and then developed over time into a full-on brawl. There were a number of events and actions that happened during the night, and a large number of NPCs we could interact with throughout the adventure.

I know our GM based it on a written adventure potentially published in the late 80's. I think it might have been published in a roleplay or specific D&D magazine, possibly a very early *White Dwarf*.

The sessions stand out even now as being really good fun, and I have been trying to find it in order to run a similar session myself. Does anyone know which one-shot adventure this was?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In "The Best of White Dwarf - Scenarios Vol. 1", published in 1980, pages 26 and 28-29 (27 was an advertisement) feature the adventure "A Bar-Room Brawl - D&D Style" by Lew Pulsipher.

Further reading of the adventure includes details of numerous characters to interact with, a hex map of a bar room, and rules for using objects in the environment like tables, chairs, or "small cauldrons of hot stew."

On a related note, a resource that I sometimes use to find old adventures is [AdventureLookup.com](https://adventurelookup.com/adventures/), which is an offshoot of a Matt Colville project and recently received a big update (at time of writing). It doesn't seem to feature old White Dwarf articles, but it does provide an index of adventures (and where to legally obtain them) from multiple publishers across various editions of D&D and Pathfinder.

Comment: That is exactly it, thankyou :)

Comment: Whoa, I think I remember that one. Nice deep dive there! Also, nice link!